# Change targetSdkVersion 30 to 31 error ionic cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

after changing targetSdkVersion to 31 I'm getting this error:

```
Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest FAILED
        Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

I've try add, but still not working

```
 <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity">
            <application android:exported="true" />
</edit-config>
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @pedrodg inside "social-sharing" and "fcm" plugins adding everywhere that hasn't android:exported . Did that by script on plugins folder and node_modules

Comment: do you mind sharing the script you used?

Comment: @pedrodg Answer the question with the script

Answer (score 1):

Script use to fix it :

```
echo "plugin explicit export:android for targetSdk 31..."
# LINUX #
sed -i -e 's/android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent" android:enabled="true"/android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent" android:exported="false" android:enabled="true"/g' plugins/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing/plugin.xml
sed -i -e 's/android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">/android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:exported="false">/g' plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/plugin.xml
sed -i -e 's/android:stopWithTask="false">/android:stopWithTask="false" android:exported="false">/g' plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/plugin.xml

sed -i -e 's/android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent" android:enabled="true"/android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent" android:exported="false" android:enabled="true"/g' node_modules/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing/plugin.xml
sed -i -e 's/android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">/android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:exported="false">/g' node_modules/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/plugin.xml
sed -i -e 's/android:stopWithTask="false">/android:stopWithTask="false" android:exported="false">/g' node_modules/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/plugin.xml


echo "fixing social sharing for android 12..."
#LINUX#
sed -i -e 's/final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);/int pendingIntentValueFLAG = 0; if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) { pendingIntentValueFLAG = PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE; } else { pendingIntentValueFLAG = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT; } final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, receiverIntent, pendingIntentValueFLAG);/g' plugins/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing/src/android/nl/xservices/plugins/SocialSharing.java
sed -i -e 's/final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);/int pendingIntentValueFLAG = 0; if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) { pendingIntentValueFLAG = PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE; } else { pendingIntentValueFLAG = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT; } final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, receiverIntent, pendingIntentValueFLAG);/g' node_modules/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing/src/android/nl/xservices/plugins/SocialSharing.java
```

Comment: do this script need to run after a 'after_platform_add'?

Comment: it not working in a window. while generating android build

Comment: @KishanVaishnani first add the platform and run the scripts. Then remove the platform and add it again.. this is the steps I'm following.

Comment: Please @Giulia Lage, I have the same issue but I'm using windows platform. Could you please help me to sove the issue?